# Align equal sign in algorithm in vertical line

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, algorithms

The Code described in [1] produces the following output :

[image: Algorithm Tex Output]

For the description of my algorithm I need the equal signs to be perfectly aligned in one vertical line but currently there is still a small but noticeable offset.

---

[1] TeX-Code :

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\newcommand{\algrhs}[1]{\hfill \parbox[t]{\algrhswidth}{#1}}

\begin{algorithm} [H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $A_1 = B_1 + C_1 $ \algrhs{$ A_2 = B_2 - C_2$}
    \State $X_1 = Y_1 + Z_1$ \algrhs{$ X_2 = Y_2 + Z_2$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that the equation sides have equal width. That can be achieved by placing the smaller elements inside a box of larger width via `\makebox` (`X_x` is wider than `A_x` and `B_x +/- C_x` is wider than `Y_x +/- Z_x`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,calc}

\newcommand{\mathbox}[3][r]{\makebox[\widthof{$#2$}][#1]{$#3$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $\mathbox{X_1}{A_1} = B_1 + C_1$ \hfill $\mathbox{X_2}{A_2} = B_2 - C_2$
    \State $X_1 = \mathbox[l]{B_1 + C_1}{Y_1 + Z_1}$ \hfill
      $X_2 = \mathbox[l]{B_2 - C_2}{Y_2 + Z_2}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I've made `\mathbox` act like `\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{<stuff>}` and [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) for measuring the width of something via `\widthof`.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Can not upvote due to my low reputation value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`\eqmakebox[<tag>][<pos>]{<text>}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to set all `<text>` with alignment `<pos>` under the same `<tag>` within the same width box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $\eqmakebox[lhs1][r]{$A_1$} = B_1 + C_1$ \hfill
      $\eqmakebox[lhs2][r]{$A_2$} = \eqmakebox[rhs2][l]{$B_2 - C_2$}$
    \State $\eqmakebox[lhs1][r]{$X_1$} = Y_1 + Z_1$ \hfill 
      $\eqmakebox[lhs2][r]{$X_2$} = \eqmakebox[rhs2][l]{$Y_2 + Z_2$}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```